# Creating a javascript library closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I've been developing a JavaScript library similar to Underscore.js and Jquery in the past few days. In both of those libraries they use an object which can accept parameters but can also have methods called on it: $("param").method(); or _("param").method();

I've been reading through the source code on both of these libraries trying to understand how they are implementing such a thing but have been unable to figure it out. I do not know the name of this type of closure so I've been unable to search for it.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm just trying to figure out how I can implement an object of this type into my library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just make a function that returns an object that has methods. Example:

```
function test(demo) {
  return {
    show: function() { alert(demo); }
  };
}

test("Hello world").show();
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to have 'test' return a certain value instead of the methods object literal if no method is called on it? I've tried doing some things with flags but haven't had any luck. What I need: test("param").method1("edit param").method2("return param")

Answer (score 4):

```
var lib = (function (param) {

   var func = function () {
     /// your code

     return {
         animate : function () {
          // do the animation
          return this;
     }
   }

   return func;
})();
```

You could use

```
lib(function(){}).something();
lib("selector").something().something().something();
lib(DOMElement).something().something().something();
```

Defining

```
lib.prototype={
some: function() {}
};
```

allows you to use

```
lib("foo").some();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do anything special, just make a function and add attributes (some of which can be functions):

```
function a(){
   alert(1);
}

a.b = function(){
   alert(2);
}
```

Now you can do both:

```
a()
```

or:

```
a.b()
```

Comment: I wouldn't be able to access the parameters sent into the a() function from within the methods though.

Comment: @Ian Farrell: Sorry, misunderstood the question.